# Global variable initialization & finalization

Tags: c++builder-xe2

I have a critical section that is shared between two threads:

```
TCriticalSection        lock_measDataBuff;
```

I have declared this variable as global. Now because Delphi style classes must be constructed using operator new, i have modified above declaration as follows:

```
TCriticalSection        *lock_measDataBuff;
```

Where is the best place to initialize the lock variable using operator new? Where is the best place to finalize the global variable using operator delete? Should it be WinMain method? Constructor of one of the classes accessing lock variable? Or some other place in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `std::auto_ptr` or `boost::unique_ptr` to handle all of that for you, eg:

```
#include <memory>

std::auto_ptr<TCriticalSection> lock_measDataBuff(new TCriticalSection);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are creating a global variable, you will need to initialize before you create the threads, which would be main, and the best place to release the memory would be after the threads end

Comment: These are worker threads created on demand for limited time. Unfortunately my threads have the Attribute "FreeOnTerminate" set. After I call "Terminate" method I am no longer interested in them. Your suggestion would require smaller changes to code like for example calling "WaitFor" on threads and then call "delete". But it is one method how to solve this problem. I will consider this. I just thought if C++ Builder has some analogy to "initialization" and "finalization" blocks in Delphi. This would be simpler for me.